# API dispatch events for Observers

Tags: event-observer, api

I have created observers for dispatch events in Magento, for example `customer_save_after`. Are there events to observe similar events handled through the API?

Answer (score 3):

Taking a quick look at the Magento API files; shows that it goes through a different logic code base at some places, but still trigger events like the example below, inside **Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api** :

```
    public function createOrder($quoteId, $store = null, $agreements = null)
{
    $requiredAgreements = Mage::helper('checkout')->getRequiredAgreementIds();
    if (!empty($requiredAgreements)) {
        $diff = array_diff($agreements, $requiredAgreements);
        if (!empty($diff)) {
            $this->_fault('required_agreements_are_not_all');
        }
    }

    $quote = $this->_getQuote($quoteId, $store);
    if ($quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
        $this->_fault('invalid_checkout_type');
    }
    if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() == Mage_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer::MODE_GUEST
            && !Mage::helper('checkout')->isAllowedGuestCheckout($quote, $quote->getStoreId())) {
        $this->_fault('guest_checkout_is_not_enabled');
    }

    /** @var $customerResource Mage_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer */
    $customerResource = Mage::getModel("checkout/api_resource_customer");
    $isNewCustomer = $customerResource->prepareCustomerForQuote($quote);

    try {
        $quote->collectTotals();
        /** @var $service Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote */
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service->submitAll();

        if ($isNewCustomer) {
            try {
                $customerResource->involveNewCustomer($quote);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }

        $order = $service->getOrder();
        if ($order) {
```

> ```
>             Mage::dispatchEvent(
>                 'checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
>                 array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote));
> ```

```
            try {
                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
```

> ```
>         Mage::dispatchEvent(
>             'checkout_submit_all_after',
>             array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote)
>         );
> ```

```
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('create_order_fault', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $order->getIncrementId();
}
```